# Create Recurrent Server Notifications

Tags: azerothcore

Is there any way to create reccurent server notification? For example "Join our Discord server" or "/join World to join Global Chat".

I was looking for mod or some SQL table for this functionality. No results on 2023-08-07.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the auth scheme. There's the `autobroadcast` table with announcements in it. See https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/autobroadcast

If you're looking for a temporary solution, e.g. for news, feel free to try https://github.com/55Honey/Acore_TempAnnouncements